# Special case of distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

I want an example for a distribution function $F$ with those two conditions for all $\lambda>0$
$$\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac {1-F(x)} {e^{-\lambda x}}=0   $$  $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac {1-F(x)} {e^{-\lambda x}}=\infty$$
I want one example of  a distribution function where those two conditions hold.
 I may use a $F$ with $F(t)=f_k$ with $t\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]$ and choose fitting $f_k,x_k$, but i have no clue how to go on.
$$ $$Thanks Nordmann

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

If you pick positive $c_1 < c_2 < \dots$ and $a_1<a_2<\dots$ such that
$$
F(x) =\begin{cases}
0, &\qquad \text{if } x < a_1,\\[6pt]
 1-e^{-c_k}, &\qquad \text{if } a_k\le x < a_{k+1},\text{ for } k=1, 2, \dots,
\end{cases}
$$
then to satisfy these conditions it's enough to have
$$
c_k/a_k\to\infty, \qquad c_k/a_{k+1}\to 0.
$$
So, pick $c_k:=e^{(2k+1)^2}$, $a_k:=e^{4k^2}$.

Comment: You don't seem to be naive in the use of TeX like so many people here, but you use the antiquated \ {\rm blah\ blah\ blah\ } instead of \text{ blah blah blah } and the complicated {array} instead of the far simpler {cases} when it's about cases (i.e. piecewise definition).  Do you prefer those for a reason?

Comment: I guess it just shows you how long ago I learned TeX.

Comment: Im new to Tex, but i appreciate every advice

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_n=\exp(3^n)$ and $x_n=a_n^2+1$ and assume that $\mathbb P(X=x_n)=c\mathrm e^{-a_n}$ for every $n\geqslant1$, where $c$ is chosen such that $c\sum\limits_n\mathrm e^{-a_n}=1$. Note that $x_n\ll a_{n+1}$ and that, for every $n$, $\mathrm e^{-a_n}\leqslant\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n}\mathrm e^{-a_k}\leqslant2\mathrm e^{-a_{n}}$.

Then $1-F(a_n^2)\gt c\mathrm e^{-a_n}$ hence $\mathrm e^{\lambda a_n^2}(1-F(a_n^2))\gt c\exp(\lambda a_n^2-a_n)\to+\infty$.
And $1-F(x_n)\leqslant2c\mathrm e^{-a_{n+1}}$ hence $\mathrm e^{\lambda x_n}(1-F(x_n))\leqslant2c\exp(\lambda x_n-a_{n+1})\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $F(t)$ to be constant on intervals $(x_k, x_{k+1})$ with a jump at each $x_k$
from a value where $\frac{1-F(x)}{e^{-\lambda x}}$ is large (say $k$) to one where it is small (say $ 1/k$).

Comment: Sure. But why does this yield a nondecreasing F?

Comment: If $\dfrac{1-F(x_k-)}{e^{-\lambda x_k}} = k$ and 
$\dfrac{1-F(x_k+)}{e^{-\lambda x_k}} = 1/k$ with $k > 1$, you
must have $F(x_k+) > F(x_k-)$.

Comment: This does not answer my question. One would also need that $\mathrm e^{\lambda (x_{k+1}-x_k)}\geqslant k^2$ for every $k$, a condition which seems difficult to achieve for every positive $\lambda$.

Comment: Just take $x_{k+1} \ge x_k + \log(k^2)/\lambda$.

Comment: Quote: *difficult to achieve for every positive λ*. Unquote.